# Binding time difference to each element individually on keyup

Tags: jquery, momentjs, jsfiddle

**The Result**

Thank you both (@timmyRS and @LTasty) for helping out.

[image]

I am creating a bunch of transport pickups that occur before a flight departs.

1. **Flight Departure Time**
2. **Minutes**: number of minutes that pickup occurs before Flight Departs
3. **Pickup Time = Flight Departure Time - Minutes**

The Departure Time persists and is used to indicate Pickup Time based on number of minutes prior.

My starting point is;

```
<label>Flight Departs</label>
<input type="text" class="tour-time" value="10 AM" />
<hr />
<div class="pickups">
  <div><label>Pickup Time <span class="pickup-time"></span></label>
    <input type="text" class="pickup-minutes" placeholder="number of minutes before flight departs" />
  </div>
</div>
<a href="#" class="add-pickup">Add Pickup</a>
```

The Add Pickup link adds additional Pickup Times by appending.

**My Problem**

I would like to update the Pickup Time individually for each Pickup Point added.

I have the times correctly calculated but they all update together. As you can see in following screen shot. The first Pickup Time is correct (20 mins before 10AM = 9:40 AM) but it also changes the second Pickup Time which should be 9:30 AM.

[image: Pickups]

Please see [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/jabuka/u5hL9Lar/23/)

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mistake was very simple to spot as you are in-fact only calculating from the first `.pickup-minutes` element and putting it into every `.pickup-time` element. Using a simple `each` function has fixed the issue for me:

```
$(document).on('keyup', '.tour-time, .pickup-minutes', function()
{
    $(".pickups").children().each(function()
    {
        console.log(this);
        var tourtime = $('.tour-time').val();
        var minutes = $(this).find('.pickup-minutes').val();
        ctime = moment(tourtime, 'h:mm A').subtract(minutes, 'minutes').format('h:mm A');
        $(this).find('.pickup-time').html(ctime);
     });
});
```

Also: I changed the subtract method to `substract(minutes, 'minutes')` as it was deprecated in the old way.

Comment: Oh dear - brilliant. Thank you!

Comment: @Jabuka If my answer helped you fix the issue, mark it as the answer using the check-mark please. (It will also give you 2 rep.)

Comment: Waiting for 3 minutes to elapse.

Answer (score 1):

I split handler because when you change hours you need to each all input present

```
$(document).on('keyup', '.tour-time', function(e) {
      var tourtime = $(this).val();
      $(".pickups div").each(function(){
        var minutes = $(this).children(".pickup-minutes").val();
        ctime = moment(tourtime, 'h:mm A').subtract(minutes, 'minutes').format('h:mm A');
        $(this).find('.pickup-time').html(ctime);
      });

});
$("body").on("keyup",".pickup-minutes",function(){
      var tourtime = $('.tour-time').val();
      var minutes = $(this).val();
      ctime = moment(tourtime, 'h:mm A').subtract(minutes, 'minutes').format('h:mm A');
      $(this).parent().find('.pickup-time').html(ctime);
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/u5hL9Lar/29/

Comment: In tour-time i have an `each` while into the pickup-minutes i work with `parent` and `find` :)